# CakePHP Keeps Logging out on 404

Tags: php, cakephp

Not really sure what this could be, tried a hell of a lot to fix it. Works fine on local too.

But when I had a 404 page, CakePHP logs the current user out.

Using 2.2.3

Comment: Are you actually logged out across the site or is just the 404 page? If I hit an error page on my site it *displays* the page as if I am not logged in - it's something I need to look into.

Comment: Hello, i managed to work it out. Basically i had to set the php cookie domain in both htaccess and CakePHP. Not really sure what was up. Seems like a server config problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try not having your Security.level set to high. CakePHP session IDs are regenerated between requests if it is set to high, and if you have a 404, it will cause it to reset the session.